# Which Polymer lifecycle event should be used to modify contained elements before they render?

Tags: polymer

I'm writing a `<my-codeblock>` element, in which I'd like to strip leading and trailing whitespace from the content. Of the [polymer lifecycle events](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods), which is the best to use to traverse the contents of the custom element and modify them?

I definitely want to get the modification done before the first paint, and it would be nice to help the polyfill/browser avoid extra work when distributing the nodes I'm going to modify into the shadow dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, I'm working on this exact element as we speak :)

`attached()` is typically the best place to access light dom children, parent elements, or interrogate distributed nodes. From the faq:

- [How do I access the DOM in a `<content>`?](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#accessContentDOM)
- [Why do elements report zero (light DOM) children at created/ready time](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#zerochildren)
- [When is the best time to access an element’s parent node?](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#parentnode)

Something that hasn't made it to the [documentation](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/295) yet is the `domReady` callback. If you add `domReady` to the element, Polymer calls it when the element's initial set of children are guaranteed to exist. If you need to handle dynamically added/removed children, add a Mutation Observer.

Comment: It looks like `attached` and `domReady` will be generally called after the initial contents have been distributed into the Shadow DOM, which might waste time if I'm just going to change the light DOM nodes in ways that force a redistribution. Is that right? Is it just too small to worry about?

Comment: `ready()` is the earliest you can call `content.distributedNodes()` (Shadow DOM has been created at this time) but there are situations where it's too early. This is why we recommend `attached()`/`domReady()`. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/414#issuecomment-34091613

Comment: Out of date... it is Polymer 0.5